# ensemble_glmnet: could not find function "predict.cv.glmnet"

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to run the ensemble_glmnet program, but receiving an error that it cannot find predict.cv.glmnet.  I have loaded the glmnet and glmnetUtils libraries.

I'm running RStudio 1.2.5033 and R version 3.6.2

```
library(BuenaVista)
library(glmnet)
library(glmnetUtils)

data<-iris[sample(1:150, size = 150, replace = FALSE),]

data <- derive_variables(dataset=data, type = "dummy", integer = TRUE, return_dataset=TRUE)

data$Species_setosa<-as.factor(data$Species_setosa)

test <-data[101:50,c(1,2,3,4,6,7)]
data<-data[,c(5,1,2,3,4,6,7)]

ensemble_glmnet(y_index = 1, train = data, valid_size = 50, n = 10, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", type = "class")
```

> Error in predict.cv.glmnet(object = cv.glmnet(x = X, y = Y, nfolds =
>   nfolds,  :    could not find function "predict.cv.glmnet"

Comment: Hi, I think this is an issue with the `BuenaVista` package. They are calling a function which you're not supposed to use directly from `glmnet`. To use `predict.cv.glmnet` you should use the function `predict` and in the background the correct prediction function is used. A dirty hack would be to get the code from `ensemble_glmnet` and modify the code by adding `glmnet:::` in front of `predict.cv.glmnet`. But maybe better to submit an issue or merge request with the fix.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!